# Cloud based CI server that can handle concurrency blocking based on external resources

Tags: continuous-integration

I've been researching cloud based CI systems for a while now and cannot seem to find any systems that can address a major need of mine.

I'm building CI processes for development on Salesforce, but this question is more generally about builds which rely on an external resource.  In our builds, we deploy code into a cloud hosted Salesforce instance and then run the tests in that instance.  During a build, the external resource is effectively locked and build failures will occur if two builds target the same external resource at the same time.  This means that the normal concurrency model of cloud based CI systems would start tripping over the Salesforce instance (external resource) with a concurrency greater than 1.

To complicate things a bit more, we actually have 5 different external resources for each project (feature, master, packaging, beta, and release) and need to control the concurrency of any builds relying on an external resource to 1.  For example, all our feature branches build against the feature external resource.  We can identify these builds by the branch name which uses the pattern feature/* and need to ensure that only one feature build runs at a time.  However, the feature build doesn't tie up the other 4 external resources so ideally any builds that would need those resources should still be able to run concurrently.

I currently accomplish this in Jenkins using the Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin and assign a throttle group to each build identifying the external resource it relies on.  This has been successful at preventing concurrent builds from tripping over external resources.

A few clarifications:

1. I'm not asking how to reduce concurrency to 1 at the repo level.  I know every cloud CI system can do that.  I should be able to set repo concurrency to N external resources (in my case, 5).
2. Ideally, I'd like to be able to use a regex pattern on branch name as the "group" with which to block concurrence.  So, a setting like: If branch name matches 'feature/.*' then limit concurrency to 1.  I want to avoid having to manually configure new feature branches in the build system and instead match on pattern.

I have to say, it's been nearly impossible to find a restrictive Google search term that would help me answer this question.  Hopefully someone out there has faced this problem before and can shed some light for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Jenkins Pipeline plugin you can set the stage concurrency to 1 - and only 1 thing will pass through that stage at a time. The stage was designed to be able to represent things like this.

https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins

```
stage "build"
node {
   sh './test-the-awesome'
}

stage name: "environment test", concurrency: 1
node {
    sh 'tests that lock the environment'
}
```

You can put the build pipeline in a Jenkinsfile in a repo too: https://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cookbook/pipeline-as-code.html (so any branches that build, also obey that lock).

As pointed out by @Jesse Glick in the comments below, perhaps a more general solution (not yet compatible with pipeline) is to use the [Lockable Resources Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin) - which will then work across jobs, of any type.

Comment: I'm using the old Build Flow plugin along with Throttle Concurrent Builds in Jenkins now.  This definitely seems to be a better implementation.

Comment: FYI, I might wind up accepting this as the answer, but want to leave a bit more time to see if there are non-Jenkins options capable of the same type of logic.  I know how to do this in Jenkins already, but if doing it in Jenkins this is definitely the better way to do it.

Comment: This is not actually an appropriate use of `stage` and `concurrency`, which is designed for throttling with a particular semantics related to build order. Consider the multiple feature branches (logically mappable to subprojects when using _Pipeline: Multibranch_) all with contention on *one* feature resource. What you really want is the [Lockable Resources plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin), which in the case of Pipeline would be blocked by [JENKINS-30269](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30269) as of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplish this with a Drone.io setup.

Essentially, I use a grunt plugin to access a Redis db hosted externally. It provides semaphore locking on any param you'd like.

Determine if the lock is free for that Env. 
If so that Env's Key with a reasonable timeouts
Run the tests
Clear the lock

If the lock is held, get it's expiration time, and sleep until then.

Comment: So you're having the concurrency blocking occur as part of the build script itself?  I was really hoping to avoid that for a few reasons: 1. It ties up executors for a build that really should be queued  2. it skews your build times

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of any cloud based CI tools that can manage external resources the way you want to, unless you include the logic as part of the build script, which you've already said you'd prefer not to do. If you decide you want to do that you could do it with [Snap CI](https://snap-ci.com/) or Drone or any of the other cloud tools I imagine.

In this sort of situation, I would usually recommend an agent-based system such as [Go.cd](https://www.go.cd/)